# Plurals of "infimum" and "supremum"

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

The words *infimum* and *supremum* are technical terms in mathematics. Should their plurals be *infima* and *suprema* or *infimums* and *supremums*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For mathematicians, the plurals of *infimum* and *supremum* are *infima* and *suprema,* respectively. Google Ngrams shows that the incorrect plurals *infimums* and *supremums* are used roughly equally often (and much less often than the correct plurals), so I don't believe there is actually any asymmetry.

Here is the [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=infimums%2Csupremums&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5) with the incorrect plurals:[image]

They are used so infrequently that they barely show up on [an Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=infimums%2Csupremums%2Cinfima%2C+suprema&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5) if you try to compare the usage of the correct and incorrect plurals.

Comment: +1 for the other NGram, showing that the "incorrect" plurals are used but show up as flat lines when put in context of the NGram I used

Comment: Inferring from Ngrams is an incorrect conclusion since "suprema/infima" are Latin,Spanish, Italian words. Please browse the books.

Comment: @Bogdan: that may explain why *suprema* is twice as common as *infima.* However, if you just look at the books since 1990, over half of the instances of *infima* seem to be mathematical, and *infimums* is still quite uncommon.

Comment: Those are the correct plurals for classicists and generally speakers of Latin, I daresay! Mathematicians simply borrowed the words.

Comment: Peter, are you trying to be provocative when you use the word "incorrect"?  Oxford English Dictionary shows no plural at all for "infimum" or "supremum" ...!!!... but does list both plurals "extrema, extremums" for "extremum".  And of course it lists "maxima, maximums" and so on.

Comment: @GEdgar: Maybe I should have said "inferior" rather than "incorrect." But the best plural to use is obviously *...ma.* Also note that mathematicians use *minimums* much less frequently then the general populations. From Ngrams, the ratio of *minima* to *minimums* is roughly 6 to 1. On the mathematics/physics preprint server www.arxiv.org, Google shows that the ratio is more like 57 to 1, so for mathematicians, at least, I would argue that *minimums* is incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

According to this [dictionary of math terms](http://books.google.com/books?id=SRw4PevE4zUC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=plural+infimum&source=bl&ots=ZEakZo-QQB&sig=njYADGSTsmJ5OYBiYIf2VTLNs4k&hl=en&ei=za5aTsWWOYfhiALF6tCSCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=plural%20infimum&f=false), the plural of *infimum* is *infima*. Similarly, the plural of *supremum* is *suprema*.

As this [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=suprema%2C+supremums%2C+infima%2C+infimums&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows, *suprema* and *infima* are also used more than the plurals formed with an *s*.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The already given Ngrams are kind of biased since *suprema* and *infima* appear as plurals outside of mathematics. One can argue that this is the plural in general. But more than that, those words also appear in inner Latin, Italian or Spanish texts (ex. *Corte Suprema*).
I suggest Googling the books on the subject "mathematics" for the period 1950-2010.
The results show:

- [infimums](http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22infimums%22+subject%3a%22mathematics%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan%201_2%201950,cd_max%3aDec%2031_2%202010&num=10&lr=lang_en) 457 results
- [infima](http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22infimums%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan%201_2%201950,cd_max%3aDec%2031_2%202010&num=10&lr=lang_en#sclient=psy&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan%201_2%201950,cd_max%3aDec%2031_2%202010,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22infima%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&pbx=1&oq=%22infima%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=190911l192395l0l193047l4l4l0l0l0l1l437l1156l2-3.0.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=dce548614f8e8b3c&biw=1366&bih=558) 5590 results
- [supremums](http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22infimums%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan%201_2%201950,cd_max%3aDec%2031_2%202010&num=10&lr=lang_en#sclient=psy&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan%201_2%201950,cd_max%3aDec%2031_2%202010,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22supremums%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&pbx=1&oq=%22supremums%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=38703l43103l1l43919l15l15l1l0l0l3l639l3504l0.4.9.5-1l14l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=dce548614f8e8b3c&biw=1366&bih=558) 708 results
- [suprema](http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22infimums%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan%201_2%201950,cd_max%3aDec%2031_2%202010&num=10&lr=lang_en#sclient=psy&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan%201_2%201950,cd_max%3aDec%2031_2%202010,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22suprema%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&pbx=1&oq=%22suprema%22%20subject%3a%22mathematics%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=42922l43618l2l43964l4l3l3l0l0l0l234l234l2-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=dce548614f8e8b3c&biw=1366&bih=558) 8940

In conclusion, I wouldn't say *supremums*, *infimums* are incorrect, but are less used. You can't go wrong with *infima/suprema*. Note that Wikipedia math articles, such as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremum#Suprema_within_partially_ordered_sets) also use *infima/suprema*.

Answer (score 3):

*Infimum* ("the lowest") and *supremum* ("the highest") are Latin words. For the neutral genus, the plural is given by replacing -um with -a . So I would suggest doing it like the Romans: *infima* and *suprema*.

Comment: I was kidding a bit. Yes, they are in usage.

Answer (score 1):

Pluaral of Supremum is Suprema. The Plural of infimum can be either infima or infimums.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infimum) does wonders.

Comment: Okay, but how do you know Wiktionary is correct here? It doesn't appear to cite any sources.

Comment: Also, the asymmetry between the two seems implausible.

Comment: @Brennan: For mathematicians, the plurals of *infimum* and *supremum* are *infima* and *suprema,* respectively. Google Ngrams shows that the incorrect plurals *infimums* and *supremums* are used roughly equally often (and much less often than the correct plurals), so I don't believe there is actually any asymmetry.

Comment: @Peter: make this an answer so I can accept it :). ngrams is a great tool that I hadn't thought of using.